# How do I partition correctly on a dual-boot Win8.1/Ubuntu sytem?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am dual-booting my system with Ubuntu 14.04(LTS) and win8.1

(followed this guide step-by-step:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU)

And now i noticed i only have 20gb to store my data including some steam games which I tried to install.

So I figured i had to partition my Hard drive again but do not know how to do it the right way. On the Launcher I am informed on that HD icon that I have 728 GB Volume of space but it seems I cannot use it.

[image]

Comment: Please boot from LiveCD and give a link to gparted screenshot.

Comment: Do you mean the bootable USB with the Ubuntu installer? Also do I replace the content with this Gparted program?

Comment: Just boot from Ubuntu installer, run gparted and make a screenshot of it. Then post the picture to some hosting site and post a link here.

Comment: Hope i got it right http://postimg.org/image/oy6eqf15l/

Comment: Yes, you did it right. The question is what is sda5 partition. Did you create it?

Comment: And what is your RAM size? You do not have swap.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have windows installed at all on that drive...

Comment: @BrianSizemore Why? There are two NTFS partitions.

Comment: If you plan on installing 8.1 and ubuntu, I'd suggested doing a clean install of 8.1 and then using windows tool to shrink the partition and install ubuntu in the new space that shrinking has made available.

Comment: Oh, was thinking That it should be FAT partitions rather than ntfs

Comment: @pilot6 I think I did create the sda5 partition but I do not recall the purpose so it's probably my mistake. I got 4GB of RAM on this system although Ubuntu points out I only have 3.8 GB.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is FAT partition since the guide I linked mentioned it and all I did was follow it

Comment: My PC already can boot into both the OS's the only problem I have is that I can't use the 728GB of HD space on Ubuntu

Comment: But this is not EFI partition. It looks like you installed both Oses in legacy, not UEFI mode.

Comment: Is installing the OS in legacy mode a problem? Also the sda5 is supposed to be a swap area according to the video.

Comment: This is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your Ubuntu partition this way.

1. Move left side of /dev/sda2 partition left. This will shrink your Windows partition.
2. Extend left side of /dev/sda3 partition left.
3. Move /dev/sda5 left and format it as swap
4. You will be able to extend /dev/sda6 Ubuntu partition left.
5. Do not forget to press "Apply" button in gparted.

But after you move Ubuntu boot partition, you will have to re-install grub. It can be done this way. Run from LiveCD

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo chroot /mnt && sudo update-grub && exit
```

You will also need to add UUID of your swap partition to `/mnt/etc/fstab` file like this

```
UUID=ccd2f497-5d8f-48c7-9102-c339c2689ff8 none swap sw 0 0
```

You will need to run `sudo -H gedit /mnt/etc/fstab` and add a line there.

But use UUID of your /dev/sda5 partition. You can find it by clicking it in gparted and selecting properties.

Comment: I think he should need a swap partition as well?

Comment: It depends on RAM size.

Comment: He says he has only 4gigs of ram which I think indicates that a swap would benefit him.

Comment: Apparently the sda5 partition is supposed to be a swap partition.

Comment: @VictorMoraes But you did not format it right. You need to format it as swap.

Comment: @Pilot6 Format it to Linux-swap?

Comment: @VictorMoraes Exactly

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok, I could format /dev/sda5 to Linux-swap but I could not  do steps 1 and 2 since the left side of both partitions wouldn't move/extend

Comment: @VictorMoraes Did you move sda2 right side left? Post a screenshot again please.

Comment: "Move left side of /dev/sda2 partition left". Typo I guess? This is how it Looks so far: http://s18.postimg.org/aet4r2pdl/Screenshot_from_2015_07_08_21_18_20.png EDIT: Did it in the correct order

Comment: @VictorMoraes You overdone that. You made your Windows partition too small. Windows will not boot. Add some more to sda2. Move left side of sda3 right and extend sda2 to a reasonable size.

Comment: http://s13.postimg.org/bn1bk8687/Screenshot_from_2015_07_08_21_23_00.png Like so? Also I can't seem to be able to do step 4, I cannot extend /dev/sda6.

Comment: @VictorMoraes It is obvious. You can not move sda6 left, because you can move only to unallocated space. First move all sda5 left, then you will be able to extend sda6. You did not do step 3.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you. It looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/ynp2ytw6l/32f41444/

Comment: @VictorMoraes looks good. Press "Apply" it will take some time.

Comment: @VictorMoraes Maybe it makes sense to have a 4GB of swap, if you want to use hibernation.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't think it's necessary since I never use that function anyways.  Also, I'm getting a terminal error when executing (sudo update-grub --output=/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg). The error reads like this: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of ` /cow'.

Comment: @VictorMoraes If first two ran OK, you can skip the third one. You can run `sudo update-grub` after you reboot into Ubuntu.

Comment: @VictorMoraes Or do `sudo chroot /mnt && sudo update-grub && exit`

Comment: @Pilot6 That last line of code worked fine :) Now for the last step it should look like this: http://s27.postimg.org/6dhnctwhv/Screenshot_from_2015_07_08_21_57_20.png ?

Comment: @VictorMoraes Check UUIDs of sda6 and sda5 to match what you see in gparted. You added my number, but it must be yours.

Comment: @VictorMoraes And also I would remove everything below `# swap was...` except that new line.

Comment: @VictorMoraes And also you missed `sw` there. Be careful.

Comment: sda5 did not match so I changed the line to look like this also deleting what you mentioned: http://s28.postimg.org/5mysrzlkd/Screenshot_from_2015_07_08_22_04_57.png

Comment: @VictorMoraes Now looks good. You can reboot now, I hope it will succeed. Good luck! Do not forget to accept the answer by clicking check sign at the left if it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Reboot went smoothly and now I got tons of HD space! Thank you for your time and effort mate :)